# Chashmona - The 25th stop

Tags: number, chanuka, masei, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

I have noticed in [BaMidbor 33:29](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0433.htm#29) that the 25th stop that the Bnei Yisroel made in the Midbor according to Sidra Mas'ei was called Chashmonah. Chanukah starts on the 25th Kislev and (besides other things) celebrates the victory of the Chasmona'im. My question is two-fold: Is the significance of this in relation to Chanukah brought down in any meforshim? - Please provide sources. Secondly, was this actually a real place and if so, where?

Comment: Why would you think this is not a real place?

Comment: Isn't Chashmonah the 26th stop? It is only mentioned in Bamidbar 33, so I counted the list there twice...

Also, why חשמונה (with a closing ה) and not the more Aramaic spelling the family used: חשמונאים (with an א).

Comment: @MichaBerger From what I saw, חשמונה is 26th if you also count רעמסס, which is debatable, because that's where they started from.

Answer (score 1):

This connection is brought [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94#.D7.A8.D7.9E.D7.96.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.91.D7.9E.D7.A7.D7.A8.D7.90_.D7.9C.D7.97.D7.A0.D7.95.D7.9B.D7.94) on the Wikishiva page, as well as various other pages, as seen in [this google search result](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

The earliest source that I saw that actually brings this down is quite recent, the [Sefer Hatoda'ah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94) by R. Eliyahu Ki Tov (~60 years ago).  The Google books search result [here](https://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=dBJJW_ecNeWkjwSKg7TACQ&q=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94&oq=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94&gs_l=psy-ab.3...91210.93365.0.93722.3.3.0.0.0.0.213.387.2j0j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.m6eybJZ4pUc) shows a couple of other sefarim as well.

Chashmona is indeed a real place.  **The Torah says that Benei Yisrael camped there!**  [Here](http://www.truthofland.co.il/masaot/journeys_with%20pictures.htm) is a website with a couple of maps of the Masa'os, and you can see exactly where it is.  Alternatively, the Google images search [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%94&client=opera&hs=ROn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDmKHA_JzcAhUG8IMKHeU8CGcQ_AUICygC&biw=1326&bih=658#imgrc=hj1DRewXAP0okM:) has some other maps, although not all of the search results are actually maps of the Masaos.

---

*The moral of the story is that Googling can solve all of your problems.